# how to display the checked elements from a listview - android

Tags: android

I have the following listview : http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html the chaper: `8. Tutorial: Domain Model and Rows interaction`

In MyList class, in the `OnCreate()` method I've added:

```
setContentView(R.layout.button), where the layout button is containting:

<ListView
android:id="@android:id/list"
...
</ListView>
```

After pressing the OK button I would like to print all the checked elements from the ListView. How to do that? Need help. Appreciate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make the list in getModel() public. Then in the activity use the following

```
private void getSelected(){
    for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
            if(list.get(i).isSelected()){
                    Log.d(TAG,"The item is selected"+list.get(i).getName();
                    //Do the processing you need here.
            }
    }
}
```

Call getSelected() method from where you want.

Comment: how to make the list in the getModel()? I need in the list just the checked elements. Please help

Comment: make the list object in getModel() function a class object. private List<Model> list = new ArrayList<Model>();

Comment: I did the getMOdel method public. I am gioing to insert the methos you wrote and test it. WIll this methid print all the selected element? I want to create a list that keeps the selected elements till I delete them programatically. How to do this? Thx!!

Comment: IT WORKS!!! HOW TO PUT THIS IN A LIST AND DISPLAY THEM IN A NEW LAYOUT ON THE CLIENT SIDE?

Answer (score 0):

Create an arraylist of strings in your activity..

```
list str = new list();
```

and in onclick of your list items.. check if that specific check box is checked or not..

```
if(CheckbxsetChecked(true))
{
 str.add(**"text in that row"**)
 }
 else if(CheckbxsetChecked(false))
   {
 str.remove(**"text in that row"**)
 }
```

now display this list with new adapter in onclick of your button

Comment: what is list ? can you please tell me exactly where to it? There is no list in adnroid. Do you mean LIstView?